# Как апдейтить вложенные элементы в массиве вложенных элементов в базе данных mongo.db?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, typescript, mongodb, angular

Предположим у меня есть массив данных, включающих файлы и папки. В каждой Папке содержатся 2 вложенных массива: один из файлов, другой - из папок. В каждой папки последнего вложенного массива также содержатся папки, в которых... и так далее. Древовидная структура.

Допустим я удаляю элемент в папке с определенной вложенностью на фронте. Как мне правильно обновить свою структуру данных, чтоб изменения сохранились?

Я использую mongoose если что

Массив данных (пока в typescript) выглядит вот так:

```
  private bookshelf: any = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Im Westen nichts Neues',
      description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
      imageLink:
        'https://img.yakaboo.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/398x565/234c7c011ba026e66d29567e1be1d1f7/7/4/74431_60714327.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Der Funke Leben',
      description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
      imageLink:
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Books',
      isDeletable: true,
      includedFiles: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Der Funke Leben',
          description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
          imageLink:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
        },
      ],
      includedFolders: [
        {
          id: '5',
          name: 'Thrillers',
          isDeletable: true,
          includedFiles: [
            {
              id: '6',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: '7',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: '8',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
            {
              id: '9',
              name: 'Der Funke Leben',
              description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
              imageLink:
                'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
            },
          ],
          includedFolders: [
            {
              id: '10',
              name: '2007',
              isDeletable: true,
              includedFiles: [
                {
                  id: '11',
                  name: 'Der Funke Leben',
                  description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
                  imageLink:
                    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
                },
                {
                  id: '12',
                  name: 'Der Funke Leben',
                  description: 'The book by author Eirch Maria Remarque',
                  imageLink:
                    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71-dnZuZ0pL.jpg',
                },
              ],
              includedFolders: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Фронт выглядит как-то так

[image: Дерево файлов-компонентов]

Как правильно построить запрос "remove selection"?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от контекста

**1.** Если это POC или тестовое задание тогда можно было бы обходить "документы" рекурсивно при этом выстраивая "путь" из id. Но єто путь в некуда т.к. монго документ имеет ограниченный размер, не более 16Мб и по закону Мерфи в системе появится хотя бы один "жирный" каталог и тогда могут начаться проблемы.

**Проще и правильнее**
**2.** Ознакомиться с подходами хранения древовидных структур в [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) и просто переделать солюшн пока не поздно.

Comment: Не будет ли лучшим решением использовать sql базу данных, чтоб не приходилось эмулировать никакие связи, а использовать для этого ключи.